# Are these complexity class answers correct?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

### So for the first set here is what I calculated and what I deduced.

Size: **1000**, Time: **.1138**, Each Operation: **.0001138**

Size: **2000**, Time: **.4586**, Each Operation: **.0002293**

Size: **4000**, Time: **1.904**, Each Operation: **.0004760**

Size: **8000**, Time: **7.456**, Each Operation: **.0009320**

-> **Complexity Class (each operation)**: Every time the size grows by 2 times, the time grows by 4 times. I believe this is O(N^2).

Here is the next set, after I modified some classes to see how the performance would change.

Size: **1000**, Time: **.1266** Each Operation: **.0001266**

Size: **2000**, Time: **.5366** Each Operation: **.0002683**

Size: **4000**, Time: **2.221** Each Operation: **.0005552**

Size: **8000**, Time: **8.811** Each Operation: **.0011013**

-> **Complexity Class (each operation)**: Every time the size grows by 2, the time grows by 4, so therefore this is also a complexity class of O(N^2)?

Answer (score 0):

Your answers are inconsistent - the time complexity class for each operation is in fact O(N); but the total time complexity class is indeed O(N^2)

An easier way to check this would be to plot a graph of log(time) against log(size), and calculate the gradient. Doing this avoids having to deal with multiplicative constants.

For the first set Excel gives O(N^2.031), for the second O(N^2.082). So pretty close to the model value.

Comment: Thank you. I was actually able to deduce this earlier. As for sets that do not change over large values, the time complexity would be O(logN), right?

Comment: @Xari No. O(1) - 'cause it's constant.